# Proper way to achieve inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, abstract-class

I have this abstract class: `FooAbstract`, and two classes extending it: `FooSingleInstance` and `FooMultiInstances`.

```
public abstract class FooAbstract {
    private boolean single;

    public FooAbstract(boolean single) {
        this.single = single;
    }

    public boolean isSingle() {
        return single;
    }
}

public class FooSingleInstance extends FooAbstract {
    private Bar bar;

    public FooSingleInstance(boolean single) {
        super(single);
    }

    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }
}

public class FooMultiInstances extends FooAbstract {
    private Map<String, Bar> barMap;

    public FooMultiInstances(boolean single) {
        super(single);
    }

    public Bar getBarFromKey(String key) {
        return barMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

And I have a method `doSomethingWithBar(FooAbstract foo)`:

```
public void doSomethingWithBar(FooAbstract foo) {
    if (foo.isSingle()) {
        Bar bar = ((FooSingleInstance) foo).getBar();
        //do something with bar
    } else {
        //some logic to get key
        Bar bar = ((FooMultiInstances) foo).getBarFromKey(key);
        //do something with bar
    }
}
```

The code kind of achieves what I was intended to achieve, but I don't feel it is adhering to coding principles. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: In which class is the doSomethingWithBar located?

Comment: Some external class.

Comment: Why are you making FooAbstract as an abstract class, when it does not have any abstract method.

Comment: @SaurabhJhunjhunwala, agree. I should not make it abstract.

Comment: if you make it abstract class , you should have some abstract methods .. if not then what is the purpose of making that class abstract

Comment: The `single` property seems off. This should apply only to the instance that may reference multiple instances. Only 1 subclass has this possibility, so it should be declared in that subclass. Don't add propertied to your superclass that don't apply to all subclasses

Comment: you are deciding on the basis of `foo.isSingle()` but it might be same for both child class object.

Comment: Your class might extend any class, need not be an abstract always. you will surely achieve the same functionality.

Comment: Leave your class abstract. Although it doesn't contain any abstract methods, it's not somethin that should be instantiated, and abstract enforces that. If an abstract class contained only abstract methods, then it should be an interface. But from what I see, you are using abstract properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add:

```
public abstract class FooAbstract{

    // add abstract method to get bar
    public abstract Bar getBar(String key);
}
```

and implement it differently in FooSingleInstance & FooMultiInstances:

```
public class FooSingleInstance extends FooAbstract{
    private Bar bar;
    @Override
    public Bar getBar(String key) {
        return bar;
    }
}

public class FooMultiInstances extends FooAbstract{
    private Map<String, Bar> barMap;
    @Override
    public Bar getBar(String key) {
        return barMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

And the usage is just:

```
Bar bar=foo.getBar(key);
```

BTW I don't see any reason to use `single` field.

Answer (score 3):

## Why do you *care* what type of `Foo` you have?

Take your class and add an `abstract` method:

```
public abstract class FooAbstract {
    public abstract Bar getInstance(String key);
}
```

Now you implement that method in your different versions however you want:

```
public class FooSingleInstance extends FooAbstract {

    private Bar bar;      

    @Override
    public Bar getInstance(String key) {
        return bar;
    }
}
public class FooMultiInstances extends FooAbstract {

    private Map<String, Bar> barMap;

    @Override
    public Bar getInstance(String key) {
        return barMap.get(key);
    }
}
```

Now all you need to do is:

```
public void doSomethingWithBar(FooAbstract foo) {
    final Bar bar = foo.getInstance(key);
    //do something with bar
}
```

Now, given that your `FooAbstract` has no variables or logic, it might make sense to make it an `interface`:

```
public interface BarFactory {
    Bar getInstance(String key);
}
```

Comment: Both the answers -  this and one given by @BobTheBuilder solve the problem. Accepting the other one just because of lower timestamp.

Comment: @santosh-patil But you should think about the `interface` suggestion given in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can overload method doSomethingWithBar like that:

```
public void doSomethingWithBar(FooSingleInstance foo) {

}

public void doSomethingWithBar(FooMultiInstances foo) {

}
```

Comment: That would only work if the instance is not referenced as a `FooAbstract`. Java's methods are wired at compile time and not runtime.

Comment: This works perfectly for `doSomethingWithBar(Foo foo)` but the question still remains for some method with signature `doSomething(NotBar notBar)`.